# Add Filter Using WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've been trying to figure out how to add some content after the out_of_stock_add_to_cart_text but I can't figure out how to do it. I currently have:

```
add_filter( 'out_of_stock_add_to_cart_text', 'ie_out_of_stock_add_to_cart_text', 1000 ); 
  function ie_out_of_stock_add_to_cart_text($content) {
  $content.='<p>Currently out of stock</p>';
return $content;
}
```

But all this does is add the "Currently out of stock" message to the button, which makes a huge button. I'd like to have it display immediately after.

I'm stumped

Answer (score 0):

You would need to modify the corresponding template, which is `loop/add-to-cart.php`. Copy this from the woocommerce templates folder to `yourtheme/woocommerce/loop/add-to-cart.php` and  add your own text after line 17 (which is the line that contains the button link).

Comment: Thanks. I did that earlier and it works fine but I was just looking to see if it was possible via the use of a WooCommerce filter

Comment: it's not - this is the only way to do it, as you can see there are no other filters in this template. What's wrong with using the template?

Comment: Nothing. I'm going to use it now. Thanks.